# How can I migrate the Apple KMLViewer example to my project?

Tags: ios, mapkit

My first project deals with mapping and a KML file.

I have successfully added a Map View to a View Controller.  When I run the project, I get the standard map of the USA.

Next, I downloaded and successfully run the Apple KMLViewer example.

My first attempt at migrating the example to my project was to copy KMLParser {h/m}, KMLViewerViewController {h/m}, and KML_Sample.kml to my project and edit my AppDelegate {h/m} so that it includes items in KMLViewerAppDelegate {h/m}.

When I run my project, I still get the standard start up map.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think there's also a xib you might need to bring in and hook up with.  It might also be easier to do the opposite and migrate your project into the working sample app.